# jquery filter : multiple criteria and actions

Tags: jquery, syntax

I have several `<label>` elements that I have to use jquery to assign classes to dynamically & wondering if there's a condensed/cleaner way to do it than this:

```
$('label').filter(function()
{return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Text A:";}
).closest('div').addClass('labeltextaclass');

$('label').filter(function()
{return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Text B:";}
).closest('div').addClass('labeltextbclass');

$('label').filter(function()
{return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Text C:";}
).closest('div').addClass('labeltextcclass');
```

Is there a way to fire `.filter()` once (since I'm searching `<label>` attributes) something like this:

```
$('label').filter(function() 
(
{return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Text A:";}).closest('div').addClass('textAclass');
{return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Text B:";}).closest('div').addClass('textBclass');
{return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Text C:";}).closest('div').addClass('textCclass');
);
```

or perhaps even cleaner?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $('label').filter(() => {var txt = $.trim($(this).text());return  txt === "Text A:" ||txt === "Text B:" || txt === "Text C:";}).closest('div').addClass('labeltextaclass');

Comment: Hi, that would totally work if I was assigning the `labeltextaclass` to everything, but I have to assign specific/unique class based on the label text. updated my post to make the class name differences more visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) I would suggest [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```js
$('div label').each(function (idx, ele) {
    switch (ele.textContent.trim()) {
        case 'Text A:':
            $(ele).closest('div').addClass('labeltextaclass1');
            break;
        case 'Text B:':
            $(ele).closest('div').addClass('labeltextaclass2');
            break;
        case 'Text C:':
            $(ele).closest('div').addClass('labeltextaclass3');
            break;
    }
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-style: solid;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.labeltextaclass1 {
    color: blue;
}

.labeltextaclass2 {
    color: red;
}

.labeltextaclass3 {
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
    <label>Text A:</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Text B:</label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Text C:</label>
</div>
```